# Django navbar link open in new tab

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am new to Django and I need some of the navbar items to open in a new tab. My problem is the target="_blank" does not work. I have checked that the if logic works.

Here is the code in template

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
{% for navName, navUrl, openInNewTab in navItemsList %}
    {% if navItemsList == True %}
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ navUrl }}" target="_blank"> {{ navName }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ navUrl }}"> {{ navName }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>

</div>
```

Here is the codes in view

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from navbarItems.models import navItems

def home_page(request):
    #Navigation items
    linkNames = [entry.linkName for entry in navItems.objects.all()]
    urls = [entry.url for entry in navItems.objects.all()]
    openInNewTab = [entry.openNewTab for entry in navItems.objects.all()]

    navigationItemList = list(zip(linkNames, urls, openInNewTab))

    context = {"header_title" : 'Hidden Dimsum',
    "body_title" : 'Here is the title for the webpage',
    "navItemsList" : navigationItemList}

    return render(request, template_name = 'base.html', context = context)
```

In the navbarItems.models I have the following code

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class navItems(models.Model):
    linkName = models.TextField(null = False, blank = False)
    url = models.TextField(null = False, blank= False)
    openNewTab = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
```

Comment: please add the NavItems model

Comment: Sorry added now.

Comment: all links have `active` state and `<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>` ? maybe you need to tweak little bit your model and  add `{% if .. %}` blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

views.py:

```
from navbarItems.models import navItems

def home_page(request):
    #Navigation items
    navigationItemList = navItems.objects.all()

    context = {
        "header_title": 'Hidden Dimsum',
        "body_title": 'Here is the title for the webpage',
        "navItemsList": navigationItemList
    }

    return render(request, template_name='base.html', context=context)
```

template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            {% for nav_item in navItemsList %}
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ nav_item.url }}" {% if nav_item.openNewTab %} target="_blank"> {% endif %} {{ nav_item.linkName }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Perfect and thanks!. Just a quick correction:

<a class="nav-link" href="{{ nav_item.url }}" {% if nav_item.openNewTab %} target="_blank" {% endif %} > {{ nav_item.linkName }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>